# android webview youtube iframe like in feedly?

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube

I'm making post activity that has long html that can have many youtube iframes or 0 iframes (uknown count) in it.
The default `webview` youtube iframe has a lot of bugs. It is not autoscaling on rotation, it has not full screen button, and it continues to play after exit from activity to other and a bit buggy.

But I found in feedly almost same but without these bugs. Here screenshot.

[image: click to see screenshot]

How did they do it?

Answer (score 0):

YouTube provides API to embed videos on android application. Its easy to use and very flexible. Please refer to [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-youtube-api-to-embed-video-in-an-android-app/) tutorial for integration.

Comment: Read question. Every post I render in webview can have different number of youtube iframes. It can be 0 or 10 or 5 or 3.

I know about youtube player api but I don't think I can replace different number of iframes with it in webview.

Comment: Ull have to use listview or recycler view to get this.

Comment: The post has a lot of html in it and sometimes youtube iframes in this html.

Answer (score 0):

A project that ports the IFrame API to Android can be found on [PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player).

Very easy to integrate and very smooth, but doesn't seem to work on all devices yet.

The player you posted might do it the same way. Just have a look at the source files.